# Django - send email on model change

Tags: django, email, model

I want to send an email when a specific field is changed in a model.  Is it possible?  Here is what I am looking for.   I have a profile model that includes a BooleanField that when the administrator selects to be true I want to send user an email.  I know I could put it in a "def save(self):" but, that fires off an email anytime the model is changed and the field is true.  Is there a way to have it only email if the field was changed from False to True?

Answer (score 14):

*save* method is a perfectly good place for what you want to do:

```
def save(self):
    if self.id:
        old_foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=self.id)
        if old_foo.YourBooleanField == False and self.YourBooleanField == True:
            send_email()
    super(Foo, self).save()
```

Comment: I might change the if statement to this:

if not old.field == self.field:

Comment: He wants to send email only when the value changed from False to True. So checking that values are not equal is not enough.

Comment: Was looking for a way to trigger any action when a model is changed ... looks like this is it. Thanks.

Comment: The one disadvantage to overriding save here is this: the send_email() call will be blocking until it finishes executing. The user might have to wait a non-trivial amount of time, before the page loads again. If that's not a concern, then this is fine; otherwise, I'd suggest the signal approach mentioned below.

Comment: I retract my statement about the signal approach after reading the comment about the changing value. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed See the answer with > 20 votes by Josh. You might want to look at something like django-celery-email if you think wait times for sending mail might be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [django-model-changes](https://github.com/kajic/django-model-changes) to do this without an additional database lookup:

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django_model_changes import ChangesMixin

class MyModel(ChangesMixin, models.Model):
   flag = models.BooleanField()

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def send_email_if_flag_enabled(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.previous_instance().flag == False and instance.flag == True:
        # send email
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help and only sends an email when change from false to true

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import signals
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

#signal used for is_active=False to is_active=True
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_active and User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, is_active=False).exists():
        subject = 'Active account'
        mesagge = '%s your account is now active' %(instance.username)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, mesagge, from_email, [instance.email], fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use hook a function with your models post_save using django signals (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save)

In that function use standard django mailing: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

Comment: You will not have the old value in post_save, so there wouldn't be any way of knowing if the value has actually changed or not.