# Send an e-mail notification when a Django CharField is modified via the admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-signals

I have a CharField that is normally empty. I want to send out an e-mail notification to all managers (using `mail_managers`) when the field is set to a non-empty value. Changes to this field should only happen via the admin site.

I assumed this might be something I could do via signals but I do not see an appropriate signal listed in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to send the email when the record is saved, or on some other event?

Comment: I want to send out an e-mail the first time it is saved with a non-empty value in that CharField model field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add some history to the field if you don't want updates if the field is changed again but just adding a save method to your model similar to should work:

from django.db import models

```
class Test(models.Model):
    empty_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    def save(self):
        if self.pk is not None:
            orig = Test.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if orig.empty_field != self.empty_field and len(self.empty_field) > 0:
                mail_managers ... 
        super(Test, self).save() # Call the "real" save() method
```

See
http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/save_delete_hooks/
and
[Django: When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Comment: Ahh! The history value would be the key. Gr. Hate when I miss the obvious. Once I make some sort of old_value field, I could just use the signal mechanism. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the code sorry it is late and was not thinking. You will only need a boolean field to check if the field was ever changed from empty to something IF you want to make sure that no mail is sent if the value is changed back to empty and then changed again :)

Comment: Good thinking sunn0. Appreciate it.