# post_save in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a application that i exclusively use with the admin.

I would like to send an email every time that a new object is created/modified, from my search, it seems that using the post_save would be the best way.

Unfortunately the doc is not really clear on that...

Can someone explain me > maybe with an example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways. Either override the save function or use signals.

See the following excellent posts:

- [Django Signals](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-signals/)
- [Django Signals vs Save](http://web.archive.org/web/20130802081636/http://www.martin-geber.com/thought/2007/10/29/django-signals-vs-custom-save-method/)  (linked to archive.org original removed)

For a simple similar example using save have a look at my previous answer:
[Send an e-mail notification when a Django CharField is modified via the admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160889/send-an-e-mail-notification-when-a-django-charfield-is-modified-via-the-admin-sit/4161081#4161081)