# django automated dateTime field

Tags: python, django, datetime, automation

Hello i'm working on a [blog app](https://bitbucket.org/JackLeo/django-persona) and I have a model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    <..>
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                  
    time_publish = models.DateTimeField()
    time_edit = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And i want to set that, when user sets `is_published=True` and `.save()` is called then time_publish would save current time.

The problem is that i don't know what route i should take. Overwrite `.save()` or make something with signals or what? I would appreciate some links to Docs.

Sorry if it's dublicate but i din't knew how the question of such matter should be named.

Update:

So thanks to manji i produced this code that works:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is not None:
        orig = Post.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        if not orig.time_publish and self.is_published:
            self.time_publish = datetime.now() 
        elif not self.is_published:
            self.time_publish = None
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You might also want to set `blank=True, null=True` for `time_published` if it's only going to be conditionally set by `save()`.

Comment: @Shawn Chin, already did that :) thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution (and django compliant) is to override your model's `save` method.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_published:
            self.time_publish = datetime.now() # don't forget import datetime
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
```

More informations here: [Overriding predefined model methods](http://here%3a%20Overriding%20predefined%20model%20methods)

Comment: Or as found out override `clean` method that validates forms. But save would be better place i think

Comment: @JackLeo you wouldn't want to do that in `clean()` or you may end up with inconsistent data when when models are populated without forms.

Comment: but in this case every time i modify object it rewrites publish date. is there any flag `is modified`?

Comment: found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed