# Creating a custom signal for when a user activates his account

Tags: django, signals

I am trying to create a custom signal for when the field `auth_user.is_active` becomes 1. I looked at Django's docs on signals, but was having trouble understanding how to implement custom signals.

When a user account becomes active, I want to execute the following function:

```
def new_user(sender, **kwargs)
    profile = User.objects.get(id=user_id).get_profile()
    return RecentActivity(content_object=profile, event_type=1, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
```

How would I do this. And also, what is the advantage of using signals over just doing the database insert directly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something when the field is changing, you can use [the approach suggested by Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793323), which is essentially to override the `__init__` method.

Signals are generally used to communicate between apps. For example [auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) app sends `user_logged_in` signal. So if you want to do something when user is logging in, you just handle this signal, no need to patch the app.

Comment: what if I only want to send a signal on the first user log in?

Comment: @David542 You should store a flag like `signal_sent` somewhere. BTW is it possible in your application that user will become inactive again? If not - here's the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did:

```
# in models.py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='get_active_user_once')
def new_user_activation_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_active and User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, is_active=False).exists():
        profile = User.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).get_profile()
        RecentActivity.objects.create(content_object=profile, event_type=1, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Have you clicked the link I provided? You can do it without extra DB query.

Comment: @DrTyrsa -- the auth app link? I wasn't quite sure how to do it without an extra db query. Could you please elaborate with what you mean (a code sample would be great). Thank you.

Comment: @David542: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. IMO, this should be accepted answer. The currently accepted answer is just general advice referencing external links.