# Django: Denying model saves based on particular criteria

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model, that is incredibly simple:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to deny saving of this model if the actual name changes, but I want to allow changes to capitalisation. So for example:

```
SAM -> sAm: allowed
Sam -> SAM: allowed
Sam -> John: not allowed
```

How can I override the `save()` method of my Person model so that such edits are denied? Particularly, I'm struggling with:

1. Gaining access the pre-save version of the object in the `save()` method.
2. Showing a message to the user within Django's admin area when a save is denied.
3. Returning a user back to the edit screen when a save is denied.

Feel free to answer any part of the question on its own, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed) has two good methods to detect whether a field has changed and do something.

In your case you'd modify it to not just detect if a field has changed but also detect if it's a change you want to allow.

Comment: Thanks, one of the answers there works really nicely. Do you know of any way to pass a nice message back to the user interface from the `save()` method? It doesn't look like you can use the in-built messages in Django, as you don't have access to the `request` object.

Comment: @Sam `save()` could be invoked w/o `request`, for example in Python shell, its not the right place to access request inside `save`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a form and some custom validation in the "clean" method:

example:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        name = cleaned_data.get("name ")
        if name == ###:
            #custom validition checking here
            raise forms.ValidationError('You can only capitalize.')
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: A good answer, thanks, but I really want to enforce this at the model level - rather than on a specific form.