# Initialize django model capturing a derivative attribute from that moment

Tags: python, django

I have a model with the following fields:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
impact = models.IntegerField(default = value)
```

Where I want `value` to be `User.get_profile().someIntField` with User being the same User object that was passed to the first field.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.impact = self.user.get_profile().someIntField
```

Comment: won't this completely break the way the model is initialised?  don't you need to call `super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: accepted your answer after a quick read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed - although I called to super for the init.

Comment: cheers, I edited the super in. Feel free to make corrections - i'm not testing it whereas you probably are ;-)

Comment: I'm tempted to edit your question to hold a more relevant subject. Like "Initialize django model capturing a derivative attribute from that moment?" or some such.  Can you do that? It's not very search findable as it stands.

Comment: Your variant means that you will hit user profile every time you create object. But as I understand Ferguzz need to get default impact value only when saving

Answer (score 3):

Override `save` method in your model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    impact = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.impact = self.user.get_profile().someIntField
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: but I only want to initialise this value, not reset it every time i save the model object.

Comment: is there a parameter i can get to in save() which tells me i'm creating the object?

Comment: I updated my answer. If object is created (not updated) impact value will be set. I think it is what you need