# Attribute error with custom model attribute

Tags: django

in order to check if a field has changed, I added an attribute to my model, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793323/326849):

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

  __original_name = None

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Person, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__original_name = self.name

  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.name != self.__original_name:
      # name changed - do something here

    super(Person, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
    self.__original_name = self.name
```

I already had instances of this model (without the __original_name attribute), and when I want to modify and save one, I get

```
'Person' object has no attribute '__original_name'
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: Could you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute can be accessed using `self._Person__original_name`.