# django - custom field that has another field as reference

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom field that has an image field as a reference, i use my field as below:

```
 poster = ImageField(upload_to=get_path, null=True, blank=True )
 cropping = CropField('poster')#this is my custom field
```

Now i need a way to listen  referenced image field changes... I think i can use signals in models.py but i need a dry way. I do not want to place a signal for every model that has cropping custom field.

I think i need a way to do it in custom field code.  But where?  in FieldDescriptor? in FieldCreator?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but have you looked into [django-image-cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping)?

Comment: I do not want to use another library. Because i am already working with sorl thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine whether an underlying property of a model has changed, you can overwrite the save method to do the check.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361547/2040872) describes how you can do that.

To make it available to any model that has a `CropField`, you can create an abstract base class for your models that use `CropField`

```
class CropFieldModel(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #logic to determine which field is an imageField.
        attrs = dir(self)
        for attr in attrs:
            if isisntance(attr, CropField):
                #whatever logic you want to to modify the object
        super(CropFieldModel, self).save(*args, **kw)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then all your models that use `CropField` you can just subclass `CropFieldModel` and you will get the custom save function.

```
class MyModel(CropFieldModel):
    poster = ImageField(upload_to=get_path, null=True, blank=True )
    cropping = CropField('poster')
```

This will allow you to not have to repeat yourself and provide you custom logic whenever a model instance changes.  You can also use `getattr` to invoke a function defined in your subclass if you want each model to have different behavior when it's changed.  I'm not for sure what you are trying to accomplish with your custom field but hopefully this points you in the right direction in creating your custom model and fields.

Comment: Is this the only choice?

Comment: Do you think putting the signal inside contribute_to_class definition of custom field is a good way?

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with `contribute_to_class`.  From the limited documentation on it, it sounds like it's invoked on creation of a field.  If it's being called everytime `save()` is called on your model, then sure you have another point before your model is saved to run your code.  That said, it's awkward from a scope perspective as you are looking for changes to `ImageField`, which is naturally outside the internal scope of `CropField`.  It makes more sense to me to handle this from a model perspective due to the scope of handling the interactions between multiple fields.