# Django model.save(): Check if ANYTHING changed

Tags: python, django

The question is straight forward:

Is there a way to check whether any fields of an instance have been modified in model.save() method? Or maybe other method, .clean()?

The point is that you cannot explicitly name the fields to do the checking.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Answer (score 2):

Way to get *all* field names:

```
[field.name for field in MODEL._meta.fields]
```

Way to check field value by fields name as string:

```
getattr(obj, field_name)
```

so you can modify this [Django: When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed) answer like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kw):
    if self.pk is not None:
        orig = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        field_names = [field.name for field in MyModel._meta.fields]
        fields_stats = {}
        for field_name in field_names:
            fields_stats[field_name] = getattr(orig, field_name) != getattr(self, field_name)
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

dictionary `field_stats` will be like

```
{
    'field_name1': True,
    'field_name1': False,
}
```

Where `True` means field has changed, and `False` mean field hasn't changed

Comment: Thanks for the help, but actually the marked answer in that link is not my first choice. I think the answer about ModelDiffMixin is more promising.