# Check if Django model is getting saved or deleted inside the model's init method

Tags: django, methods, orm, model, init

How can I check inside a Django model's **init** method, whether the object is about to get saved or deleted. I'd like to do some stuff *only* before the save or deleted method gets called.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Book, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.is_about_to_get_saved_or_deleted:
            do_something()
```

To say a few words about the *why*:

I need to implement live Elasticsearch search index updates. Therefore, I need to check whether certain model field values are changes or if an object gets deleted. Delete is not a problem. However, to see if field values have changed inside the save method, I need to store a heap of values inside the init method first:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793323/996638

But the init method also gets called when merely *reading* an object. In order to prevent the overhead, I'd like to store the relevant (old) field values only if the object is about to get saved. This would require only one IF statement as overhead.

Comment: IMO, `__init__` is not the best place to check to see if the object is being created/edited/deleted. But, if you absolutely need to do that, *new* objects do not have a `self.pk` if that is what you are looking for. In fact, the view might be a better place to figure out this logic instead of the model.

Comment: I know about the "PK trick", but that doesn't help here. And yes, really, I know what I'm doing there.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Okay, I've just added an explanation to what I'd like to do.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. Instantiating an object is completely separate from what might happen to it later. Where is the information stating "about to be deleted" supposed to be coming from?

Comment: I meant 'deleted' is not a problem, because I don't need the old values for that. It's just the save method that I'd like to check for ... Is there a Python native way of finding out which class method is about to get called?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: I think that is actually the answer to my question - it's not possible inside the init method, as far as I could learn. If you post it, I'll accept it as correct.