# order queryset by strip_tags(html string)

Tags: python, html, django, sorting, strip-tags

Within my django application, I have to sort a queryset by a string attribute. That's easy stuff. But this string attribute has HTML tags, which I need to strip off for sorting.

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    authors = models.CharField()
```

I know of the queryset.order_by() method, but as far as I know I can't use any method to strip html there.

I have come up with an "almost solution".

```
>>> from django.utils.html import strip_tags
>>> sorted(Publication.objects.all(), key=strip_tags('authors'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/cms/venv2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/cms/venv2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 156, in strip_tags
    if not ('<' in value or '>' in value):
TypeError: argument of type 'operator.attrgetter' is not iterable
```

How to sort this queryset? Is my approach going in the right direction? Is it efficient? Those queryset are currently up to +-1500 elements long.

Thanks in advance.

.sogeking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work the way you do it.
The `strip_tag` operation needs to take place at the database level, not in Python.

I believe the most efficient solution would be adding a field to your model — say `authors_stripped` — to store the same content as the `authors` field but stripped from tags. You can then order by that field.
A simple way to make sure `authors_stripped` matches `authors` would be to override your model's `save` method:

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags


class Publication(models.Model):
    authors = models.CharField()
    authors_stripped = models.CharField(editable=False)

    def __save__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.authors:
            self.authors_stripped = strip_tags(self.authors)
        super(Publication, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can use the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793323/1644198) to only compute `authors_stripped` value when the value of `authors` changed.

The solution proposed by @itzmeontv will work if and only if you retrieve all publications from the database which will prove to be an efficiency issue with big sets of data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sorted(Publication.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x[strip_tags('authors')])
```

or use `operator.itemgetter`

```
import operator
key=operator.itemgetter('authors')
```

**OR**

```
Publication.objects.all().order_by(strip_tags('authors')) #ascending
Publication.objects.all().order_by('-'+strip_tags('authors')) #descending
```

Comment: Uhm, that's a good one. Almost there! ( TypeError: 'Publication' object has no attribute '\__getitem__' ).

Comment: same result for operator.itemgetter :-)

Comment: Your 3rd suggestion is ok, I had come up to it by myself. But how can I strip html tags in there? The authors property is full of html trash which we do not want for sorting.