# Django how to check if user uploaded an image file when saving model with ImageField?

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking for a way to resize, compress, and optimize the uploaded image when saving an ImageField.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', height_field='height', width_field='width', storage=S3MediaStorage())
```

My first thought was to override the model's `save()` and implement this logic there, but I don't want the resize/compression/optimization to run again if the user doesn't update the image file (i.e. if he only updates `name` or `caption` on an existing object and saves it).

1. What is a proper way to check when a new image file is uploaded to the ImageField, but not when the user only changes another field in the Model, eg. the user updates `caption` but leaves everything else as-is?
2. How can the uploaded image file be accessed in code? I.e. what is the variable that contains the actual image file that can be passed to Pillow?

edit: This is unique from [the suspected duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed). I am not asking if the field has changed, because that would always cause false positives. I am asking if the user has uploaded an image file, which I will immediately change (resize/optimize/compress), so if the user immediately downloads his uploaded image he'll find that has a different binary with a randomly generated filename, and therefore comparing the filename or binary are not valid methods to determine if the user is uploading a different image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Comment: @rnevius I've added information to differentiate this question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your model could use a different name.

Nevertheless, you can try manipulating the image through a post_save signal (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save)

```
from PIL import Image
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Image)
def crop_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    img = instance.image
    original = Image.open(img.src.path)
    # ... your code here...
```

EDIT: Apologies. Jumped the gun a bit. One of your actual problems was to not manipulate the image if it's the same. You can do it on `save()` like this (UNTESTED):

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    try:
        related_img = Image.objects.get(id=self.id)
        if related_img.image != self.image:
            crop_me(self.image)
    except Image.DoesNotExist:
        # object doesn't exist. Passing...
        pass

    return super(Image, self).save(**kwargs)

def crop_me(img):
    original_img = Image.open(img.src.path)
    # ... your code here...
```

EDIT 2: If the name changes you could save the original filename in an helper field

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', height_field='height', width_field='width', storage=S3MediaStorage())

    __original_image_filename = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Image, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_image_filename = self.image.name

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image.name != self.__original_image_filename:
        # name changed - do something here

        super(Image, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_image_filename = self.image.name
```

I am modifying another answer on the fly so there could be an error or two. Please check [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793323/2879529). There are other methods on that question that could help you.

Comment: You wrote `if not self.id` and then inside `if` block, you're doing `id=self.id`. Might want fix that. It should be `if self.id`.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out! It's also antipattern (EAFP) http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-code-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html

Comment: `if related_img.image != self.image:` This might work if I keep a copy of the original file uploaded in `related_img.image`, but it doesn't look like it'd work if I only save a copy of the original file that has been renamed to a random string and the image has been resized and compressed. Is it possible to just check if the user uploaded an image file?

Comment: @DavidTan please see EDIT 2