# Django: tracking if a field in the model is changed

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Object(Object1):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to track if there is anything inserted into the date_updated field, then create another object in another model, without overriding the save method.

For example:

```
if date_updated:
    MyModel.objects.create(type="D", user=request.user)
```

Although I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed), but still no success.

Comment: "without overriding the save method" - why do you have this requirement?

Comment: Could you also add the code which you have tried?

Comment: have you considered using the `post_save` signal ?

Comment: it is actually not a requirement, I just tried to override the save method, i also tried signals, and all the possible solutions in the link attached above, but no success.

Comment: Django signals like `pre_save` or `post_save` could be useful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/

Comment: AKS, karthikr, shang wang, i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1361547/5475621) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7934958/5475621) links, at least. also tried others.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tracker` field from [django-model-utils](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker).

Add a tracker to the model:

```
class Object(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    tracker = FieldTracker()
```

You can check in `save()` or in other places where you usually update the model:

```
if object.tracker.has_changed('date_updated'):

    create_new_object(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry, just noticed that you are referencing `request.user`. So this will NOT work for you. Since you need the particular `request` object, its probably best done in the view that the `request` object is referring to.*

With [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-save) you could compare the current instance's property value with the one currently in the database.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def check_date(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    changed = created or instance.date_updated != MyModel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).date_updated

    if changed:
        MyModel.objects.create(type="D", user=request.user)
```

Didn't test it, though.

Comment: can you please give an example of how to do this in my case? because i tried a lot of things so far.

Comment: can I get the user from kwargs here?

Comment: `pre_save` signal has not `created` arg, it is in `post_save` signal.