# Identify the changed fields in django post_save signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm using django's post_save signal to execute some statements after saving the model.

```
class Mode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    mode = models.BooleanField()


from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Mode)
def post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff
        pass
```

Now I want to execute a statement based on whether the value of the `mode` field has changed or not.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Mode)
def post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        # if value of `mode` has changed:
        #  then do this
        # else:
        #  do that
        pass
```

I looked at a few SOF threads and a blog but couldn't find a solution to this. All of them were trying to use the pre_save method or form which are not my use case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save in the  django docs doesn't mention a direct way to do this.

An answer in the link below looks promising but I don't know how to use it. I'm not sure if the latest django version supports it or not, because I used `ipdb` to debug this and found that the `instance` variable has no attribute `has_changed` as mentioned in the below answer.

[Django: When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed/28094442#28094442)

Comment: I use this library: https://github.com/craigds/django-fieldsignals

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set it up on the `__init__` of your model so you'll have access to it.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__original_mode = self.mode
```

Now you can perform something like:

```
if instance.mode != instance.__original_mode:
    # do something useful
```

Comment: Careful. This approach has drawbacks, as discussed at length [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150). In a nutshell: it's not race-proof, and can also be wrong if you have two python instances pointing to the same db row.

Comment: `instance.mode != instance.__original_mode` will throw an AttributeError because `__original_mode` will get mangled, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). The correct conditional, in this case, would be `instance.mode != instance._Mode__original_mode`.

Answer (score 67):

If you want to compare state before and after save action, you can use `pre_save` signal which provide you instance as it should become after database update and in pre_save you can read current state of instance in database and perform some actions based on difference.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def on_change(sender, instance: MyModel, **kwargs):
    if instance.id is None: # new object will be created
        pass # write your code here
    else:
        previous = MyModel.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        if previous.field_a != instance.field_a: # field will be updated
            pass  # write your code here
```

Comment: My only change for this would be `previous = sender.objects.get(id=instance.id)`

Comment: Problem with this approach is what if save failed, so the change actually does not happen but you have already execute some code in pre_save that will cause inconsistency. Only in post_save you can confirm about it.

Comment: @RajatJain Could a transaction, which begins in pre_save and commits after post_save solve this issue?

Comment: I would suggest store original_fields (that is model fields before saving) as a attribute in pre_save and compare those original_fields with new_fields (new model fields as we are in post save now) and see what is changed and add your logic

Comment: @RajatJain how do I access original_fields in post_save, as they are stored in pre_save

Comment: For anyone who this might not be working for, if your field is manytomany, you need a different signal: [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)

Answer (score 60):

Ussually it's better to override the save method than using signals.

> From [Two scoops of django](https://www.feldroy.com/books/two-scoops-of-django-3-x):
> "Use signals as a last resort."

I agree with @scoopseven answer about caching the original value on the init, but overriding the save method if it's possible.

```
class Mode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    mode = models.BooleanField()
    __original_mode = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Mode, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_mode = self.mode

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.mode != self.__original_mode:
            #  then do this
        else:
            #  do that

        super(Mode, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_mode = self.mode
```

**UPDATE IF YOU NEED SIGNALS**

Just in case you really need signals because you need a decoupled app or you can't simply override the save() method, you can use pre_save signal to 'watch' previous fields

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Mode)
def check_previous_mode(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    original_mode = None
    if instance.id:
        original_mode = Mode.objects.get(pk=instance.id).mode
    
    if instance.mode != original_mode:
        #  then do this
    else:
        #  do that
```

The problem with this is that you make changes before, so if save() has a problem you could have some issues later.
So to fix that issue, you can store the original value on the pre_save and use on post_save.

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Mode)
def cache_previous_mode(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    original_mode = None
    if instance.id:
        original_mode = Mode.objects.get(pk=instance.id).mode
    
    instance.__original_mode = original_mode:

@receiver(post_save, sender=Mode)
def post_save_mode_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.__original_mode != instance.original_mode:
        #  then do this
    else:
        #  do that
```

The problem with signals and this approach also is that you need one more query to check previous values.

Comment: What's wrong with using Signals in Django? It helps you create a workflow nicely.

Comment: @Hussain whilst methods attached directly to model and you can see its behavior in one place, signals can be placed in multiple different apps and make debugging a nightmare and code less readable. So it's not about signals are bad, but methods are more obvious, and you better stick with them if you can.

Comment: i'm currently looking for a way to detect when a foreign key value changes. the method described above works but can lead to a db query explosion.

Comment: @BradenHolt did you find a solution to that? Python crashes with stack overflow

Comment: The link in the answer is broken

Answer (score 24):

This is an old question but I've come across this situation recently and I accomplished it by doing the following:

```py
    class Mode(models.Model):
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.pk:
                # If self.pk is not None then it's an update.
                cls = self.__class__
                old = cls.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
                # This will get the current model state since super().save() isn't called yet.
                new = self  # This gets the newly instantiated Mode object with the new values.
                changed_fields = []
                for field in cls._meta.get_fields():
                    field_name = field.name
                    try:
                        if getattr(old, field_name) != getattr(new, field_name):
                            changed_fields.append(field_name)
                    except Exception as ex:  # Catch field does not exist exception
                        pass
                kwargs['update_fields'] = changed_fields
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is more effective since it catches all updates/saves from apps and django-admin.

Answer (score 10):

in `post_save` method you have `kwargs` argument that is a dictionary and hold some information. You have `update_fields` in `kwargs` that tell you what fields changed. This fields stored as `forzenset` object. You can check what fields changed like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Mode)
def post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        for item in iter(kwargs.get('update_fields')):
            if item == 'field_name' and instance.field_name == "some_value":
               # do something here
```

But there is an issue in this solution. If your field value for example was 10, and you update this field with 10 again, this field will be in `update_fields` again.

Comment: Another issue is that `update_fields` is not automatically filled. It contains the fields you explicitly pass in `save()` method.

Answer (score 8):

*I'm late but it can be helpful for others.*

**We can make custom signal for this.**

Using custom signal we can easily do these kind of things:

1. Post is created or not
2. Post is modified or not
3. Post is saved but any field does not changed

---

```
   class Post(models.Model):
   # some fields
```

**Custom signals**

**Make signal with arguments **

```
from django.dispatch import Signal, receiver
# provide arguments for your call back function
post_signal = Signal(providing_args=['sender','instance','change','updatedfields'])
```

**Register signal with call back function**

```
# register your signal with receiver decorator 
@receiver(post_signal)
def post_signalReciever(sender,**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['updatedfields'])
    print(kwargs['change'])
```

**Sending the signal from post-admin**

We sending the signals from Post admin and also save object when it actually modified

```
#sending the signals 
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   # filters or fields goes here 

   #save method 
   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):


    if not change and form.has_changed():  # new  post created
        super(PostAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        post_signal.send(self.__class__,instance=obj,change=change,updatedfields=form.changed_data)
        print('Post created')
    elif change and form.has_changed(): # post is actually modified )
        super(PostAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        post_signal.send(self.__class__,instance=obj,change=change,updatedfields=form.changed_data)
        print('Post modified')
    elif change and not form.has_changed() :
        print('Post not created or not updated only saved ')
```

**See also:**

[Django Signals official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/)

Answer (score -2):

This can be identified using **instance._state.adding**

```
if not instance._state.adding:
    # update to existing record
    do smthng

else:
    # new object insert operation
    do smthng
```

Comment: This just says whether a update happened on a row or a new row was created, The user wants to specifically know which fields were changed and what was the change by having previous instance to compare

Answer (score -4):

You can use [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) in django signals.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Mode)
def post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    # only update instance
    if not created:

        update_fields = kwargs.get('update_fields') or set()

        # value of `mode` has changed:
        if 'mode' in update_fields:
            # then do this
            pass
        else:
            # do that
            pass
```