# Django - admin approve order

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm working on a project where `Users` can order a translations. If `User` creates an order, the `translation` object is created and message sent to translators. But I want to make `admin` able to approve each `translation`.

So after creating an object `translation`, the admin has to `approve` it and then something happens.

There is no problem with approval. Just simple `Bool` attribute in `translation` model. The problem is that I want to do some things right after approval like sending message to `translators` etc. I don't know if there is some pattern for this, I was looking for something like `ChangeFieldSingal` but no success.

Could you tell me how would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the `save()` method on your model and check the current value of the flag against a cached value in your Model. You need to override the `__init__` method to cache the value:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37265149/517560