# Django model is saved twice after create

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I can't figure out how my model is being saved two times. The model is called `Job`. If customer creates an order, the `Job` instance is created. After creation, there is a signal, which alerts admin that new `Job` object has been created or edited.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Job)
def alert_admin(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        email.AdminNotifications.new_order(instance)
    else:
        email.AdminNotifications.edited_order(instance)
```

---

### **EDIT:** I've found out what causes the problem, it's a signal (very bottom of the question). But, I do need this signal so I still can't figure out how to make this work...

The problem is that `Admin` recieves two emails after `User` creates a `Job`. One email is that order has been created and the second email tells that order has been edited.

I suspect that it is caused because I've rewrited the `save` and `init` method, to create something like `signal`, when `Job` attribute - `approved` is changed.
I find that advice here [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37265149/3371056) It's because after creating a `Job`, admin has to approve it - just change `Bool` value of `approved` attribute of `Job` object.

I'm attaching `view`, where the `Job` is created and model `Job`.

**VIEW:**

```
def create_order(request):
    LanguageLevelFormSet = formset_factory(LanguageLevelForm, extra=5, max_num=5)
    language_level_formset = LanguageLevelFormSet(request.POST or None)
    job_creation_form = JobCreationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    context = {'job_creation_form': job_creation_form,
               'formset': language_level_formset}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if job_creation_form.is_valid() and language_level_formset.is_valid():
            cleaned_data_job_creation_form = job_creation_form.cleaned_data
            cleaned_data_language_level_formset = language_level_formset.cleaned_data
            for language_level_form in [d for d in cleaned_data_language_level_formset if d]:
                language = language_level_form['language']
                level = language_level_form['level']
                Job.objects.create(
                        customer=request.user,
                        text_to_translate=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['text_to_translate'],
                        file=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['file'],
                        short_description=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['short_description'],
                        notes=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['notes'],
                        language_from=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['language_from'],
                        language_to=language,
                        level=level,
                )

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/order-success')
        else:
            return render(request, 'auth/jobs/create-job.html', context=context)

    return render(request, 'auth/jobs/create-job.html', context=context)
```

**JOB:**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders', help_text=_("Customer"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    translator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='jobs', null=True, blank=True, help_text=_(u"Translator"))
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=_(u"Price"))
    language_from = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='jobs_from', null=True)
    language_to = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='jobs_to', null=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False,
                                         help_text=_(u"Very short description of this order"))
    notes = models.TextField(help_text=_("Notes"))
    text_to_translate = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text to translate', blank=True, null=True,
                                         help_text=u"Text, ktorý chcete preložiť (ak neprikladáte súbor).")
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=u"Upload file")
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, null=False, default=None)
    delivery_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('Deadline'))

    PROGRESS_CHOICES = (

        ('translator_not_assigned_yet', 'Translator not assigned yet'),
        ('in_translation_process', 'In translation process'),
        ('translated', 'Translated'),
        ('complete', 'Complete')
    )
    progress = models.CharField(choices=PROGRESS_CHOICES, max_length=40, default='translator_not_assigned_yet')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    __original_approved = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Job, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_approved = self.approved

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.approved != self.__original_approved and self.approved == True:
            send_job_alert(self)
        else:
            pass
        super(Job, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_approved = self.approved

    @staticmethod
    def get_approved_pending_jobs():
        approved_pending_jobs = Job.objects.filter(approved=True, delivery__status='pending')
        return approved_pending_jobs

    @staticmethod
    def get_open_jobs_for_user(user):
        results = set()
        candidate_jobs = Job.objects.filter(language_from__in=user.userprofile.languages_verified,
                                            language_to__in=user.userprofile.languages_verified,
                                            delivery__status='pending',
                                            ).exclude(customer=user)

        for job in candidate_jobs:
            if job.level.name <= user.userprofile.language_levels.get(language=job.language_to).level.name:
                results.add(job)
        return list(results)

    @property
    def has_translator(self):
        return self.translator_id is not None
```

**Delivery signal:**

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Job)
def create_delivery(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        delivery,created_delivery = Delivery.objects.get_or_create(job=instance)
        instance.delivery = delivery
        delivery.save()
        instance.save()
```

Comment: Can you show us the `save` and `__init__` methods you overrode in that `Job` class?

Comment: You can find it at the bottom of the question. There is a Job class I've attached. There are methods __init__ and __save__

Comment: I've added whole Job model since I'm not totally sure what could cause problems.

Comment: The `self.__original_approved` does indeed smell a bit hacky. Check out this question for a different approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed

Comment: I can't see any glaringly obvious reason why the signal would be triggered twice. I would use a line debugger such as `ipdb` to set a trace in the save method and figure out exactly what happens.

Comment: Guys, I've found out where is the problem. I'm dumbass :D There is a signal which creates object Delivery and delivery is an attribute of Job. But. This is a problem. I can't remove this signal because I need delivery to be created when job is created. I've attached the signal at the very bottom of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to have the `Delivery` instance as an attribute of  `Job`, as long as the `Delivery` model has a foreign key to it. That way, you can keep your signal without triggering a second save.

Answer (score 1):

add `dispatch_uuid` while connecting receiver as per [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals)

```
def create_delivery(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        delivery,created_delivery = Delivery.objects.get_or_create(job=instance)
        instance.delivery = delivery
        delivery.save()
    instance.save()

post_save.connect(create_delivery, sender=Job, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
```