# how to group different model updates when listening to post_save in changes

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a bunch of models in my app for which I am listening to changes with `post_save`. Additionally I have an `updated_at` field on all of those which is a timestamp that will be updated on every save operation.

Assuming a model `Question` with a one two many relationship with a model `Answer` the following happens:

If I add an `Answer` then `post_save` will be triggered for both models (because of the timestamp update on `Question`). In my use case I need to know weather the `Question` itself was modified (in addition to `updated_at`) or if `post_save` was only triggered because an `Answer` was added.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think u can use **update_fields** argument to check what question fields where modified

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Question)
def tri_qu(sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if not created and update_fields and update_fields == ['updated_at']:
        # ... post_save where triggered, because of answer was added
```

Comment: the `post_save` on its own doesn't seem to automatically receive `update_fields` and instead they need to be passed somehow. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55005137/926459 @kingraphaii provides a way to do this in his answer. Combined with your answer this is the solution.