# How can I update a Django models.DateTimeField when another, specific field in the same model is updated?

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

I have two fields in a model here:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
active_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

When `is_active` is set to `True`, I'd like `active_from` to be updated to the current datetime.

How do I go about doing this? I'm open to alternatives if there's a cleaner way of doing this with one field as well.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'd like to contain this within the model to keep things encapsulated. This will be part of an API.

Comment: Might be good to use `pre_save` signal? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-save here's an answer based on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed#answer-7934958

Comment: While a signal could be used, it is considered a best practice to use them only as a last resort according to Two Scoops of Django. FYI.

Comment: I haven't heard of it - is it written by the Django project developers?

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it is to define a `save()` method on your custom model looking for change in `is_active`. There is no easy way to achieve this: you need to manually save the previous state of the value of `is_active` by defining a custom `__init__`-method. It could look something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__is_active = self.active

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_active and not self.__is_active:
            self.active_from = datetime.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed) has some answers which might help.

Comment: What does `if self.is_active and not self.__is_active` check? I don't know what the `__` changes

Comment: the `self.__is_active` is the value of the model before the changes were applied, as set in the `__init__` method. The check basically means: if is_active is True now, and was False before, update `active_from`

Comment: this is a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've pieced together so far. It seems like the most Django-esque way of doing this, but I'm happy to be corrected if not.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import datetime

class MyModel(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

# Set active_from if active is set in an update
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def set_active_from_on_update(sender, instance, update_fields, **kwargs):
    if 'is_active' in update_fields and instance.is_active is True:
            instance.active_from = datetime.now()

# Set active_from if active is set on create
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def set_active_from_on_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.is_active is True:
        instance.active_from = datetime.now()
```

My reasoning: `update_fields` in `pre_save` seems like the right place for any logic based on particular fields updating, but `pre_save` doesn't know if `instance` will be a new entry in the database or not, so `post_save` is needed to use the `create` boolean.

I think I could also do away with `is_active` and set `active_from` to `null` when it isn't active, but that doesn't seem as safe.

Answer (score 1):

When you toggle `is_active` update `active_from` at the same time.

for example:

```
def toggle_user_active_and_update(request, *a, **kw):
    request.user.is_active = !request.user.is_active
    request.user.active_from = datetime.datetime.now()
    request.user.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the [FieldTracker](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker) from [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils). I'm going to be using this moving forwards, as it makes more complex manipulation easier during `save()`.

Comment: Would your share an example with us? Once you can