# Show change log history for model instance using django-reversion

Tags: python, django, versioning, django-reversion

Using:
**django 1.10 reversion 2.0.8.**

My question is how to show a nice list of changes done to a given model instance. By that I mean that the user can quickly see a list of all the changes (new values for fields) in all revisions. He doesn't need o see all the fields only the new values of the changed ones.

So I found that a good tool for storing changes is django-reversion. However, I cannot find a solution for my problem which as I mentioned is to show a nice change-log history for a given model instance.

I found solution that can compare two revisions **django-reversion-compare**, but that is not what I am looking for. Maybe there is a better tool for that ?

The task is too quickly show to user what was changed by who and when. The model is simple and doesn't store a lot of data. It does store however foreign keys.

Comment: What did you do eventually ?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking to do the same, and after reading up a few SO posts, docs etc., it seems I had to roughly choose the solution from one of the following 3 approaches:

1) **Fetch the existing model instance before saving the new model instance**. Compare each field. Put the changed field in reversion.set_comment('(*all changes here*)'). Continue with saving the model instance.

2) **Save a copy of the old fields separately in model's  __init__()** and later compare the new fields with them (in model's save()) to track what changed. Put the changed fields in reversion.set_comment('(*all changes here*)'). Continue with saving the model instance. (This approach will save a DB lookup)

3) **Generate a [diff](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8.1/diffs.html) using django-reversion's [low-level API](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8.1/diffs.html)** and integrate with the Admin somehow

I ended up using **[django-reversion-compare](https://github.com/jedie/django-reversion-compare)** which worked great for me showing the edits wiki-style (which may be using (3) above anyways)

django-reversion's developer also [confirmed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-reversion/_vzvnHsRBFI) (3) as a better option which also avoids race condition.

If you would like to explore different options, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed) is a great SO post with lots of good ideas with their pros/cons.

(I am also on Django 1.10)