# Return just changed fields in django models

Tags: python, django, django-reversion

On my app I am using django-reversion and django-reversion-compare apps extensions to controll object version.

When I update object outside admin I would like `set_comment()` with just updated fields. How can I access to list of updated fields and set they as comment of that reversion?

I understand when I compare object version I see which fields was changed, but I want have preview in table history of changes.

I was trying do this by `django-dirtyfields`, but it was return all fields.

Add objects:

```
with reversion.create_revision():
    # create or update if exists
    p = Product(reference='010101', name='new name')
    p.save()
```

Model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
```

Comment: I ended up using this mixin, it works pretty well even with Django 1.11 – http://stackoverflow.com/a/13842223/3776299

Comment: This is helpful, but I do not know how to use in my case. I am updating exist object and define new arguments arguments so `self.__initial` and `self._dict` are equal.