# How to compare the changes in a modelform with model (django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I do not know how to compare if a modelform is equal to a model in django.
thank you very much

> ## **models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    dni = models.BigIntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    status = models.BooleanField()
    departament = models.ForeignKey(Departament) #char
```

> ## **forms.py**

```
class Form_Person(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = ['name', 'lastname', 'dni', 'address', 'phone', 'email', 'position', 'status', 'departament']
```

> ## **views.py**

```
@auth.decorators.login_required(login_url='login')
def persons_person(request,id='id'):
    page_name = 'Persons'
    try:
        person = models.Person.objects.get(id=id)
        list_departaments = models.Departament.objects.all()
        list_departaments = list_departament.exclude(name = person.departament)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_person = forms.Form_Person(request.POST, initial='person')
```

> Here the comparison would be implemented

```
        ### code to compare ###
        #   if form_persona.is_valid() and form_person.has_changed(): #Something like that
        #     ***how to compare***
        #     form_person.save()     
    except models.Person.DoesNotExist as e:
        person = None
        list_departaments = None
return render(request, 'app/persons/person.html',
             {'page_name':page_name,
              'person':person,
              'list_departaments':list_departaments})
```

Comment: 1. Don't use string as a default value for id, better will be to use None.

Comment: `initial='person'` is also wrong, user `initial=person` to pass person with that id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Answer (score 0):

The link in the duplicate flag suggests using save method on object (same can be done in form also). I would personally suggest using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) with pre_save option to check before saving.