# Detect field change in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to detect that field in Django model has been changed?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    my_current_price = MoneyField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True,
                                  verbose_name=_('My original price'))
    my_eur_price = MoneyField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('My price in EUR'))
    my_usd_price = MoneyField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('My price in USD'))
```

The thing is that I need to recalculate EUR and USD price anytime when `my_current_price` is changed.

I have two ideas:

> 1. Somehow override `MoneyField` and send signal when the field is changed.
> 2. Override save method and create a new attribute `__my_current_price` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed) - this works but it makes code very unclear for me.

**EDIT:** 
I store the price in different currencies because of faster database lookups.

Comment: yes use signal for post_save, when current_price will be changed according to it, the other 2 fields will be calculated and saved

Comment: How can I then detect that current_price is changed?

Comment: @Exprator Oh yes, you mean this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934958/3371056 It seems good.

Comment: yes thats what signal i was talking about :)

Comment: Although this is a good way, I'm thinking about using pre_save - is it possible? With pre_save, there would be just one commit. I'm not sure if I can access objects not commited changes in pre save.

Comment: its better to use in post_save as you will get the actual value as the signal will confirm the value has been saved

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to create a signal and compare `instance` with an object from database. But it seems that better way is to override `save` method which is a best practice.

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    old = Model.objects.filter(pk=getattr(self,pk,None)).first()
    if old:
        if old.attr!=self.attr:
            # attr changed
    super(Model,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: QuerySets are lazy, using them as a boolean value will execute a corresponding query in the database. Instead remove the `.first()` and check the existence of the instance by doing `old.exists()`