# Check in the save method if the field's value has changed

Tags: python, django

I've got model, which has 'active' field, I'd like to do action if it's value has changed

```
class Good(TimeStampedModel):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
    #if self.active has changed:
    #do_something()
        super().save(self, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed

Comment: Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/

Comment: @AnupYadav signals should not be used when you can do the job in the model itself. Actually the point of signals is to let _other applications_ hook into your own app without having to monkeypatch or fork it.

Comment: The solution mentionned in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1355150/41316 is fine but won't handle race conditions (ie if someone else already updated your record's `active` field in the meantime). Depending on what `do_something()` is actually about and how problematic it would be if it was executed twice, you may want to check against _both_ the original value (as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1355150/41316 AND the current db value (reloading the model from db).

Answer (score 0):

If this suits you, there is a FieldTracker utility on django-model-utils:
[django-model-utils docs](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker).
You can check the current value against the previous value of the field that you want to track.