# save(force_update=True) returns is None DJANGO, it is possible to return with rows affected?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-postgresql

SGBD is PostgresSQL

I am using it to identify if there has been a change, if I would make an update in a date and time field, since once using `auto_now = True` it always enters my model and makes the update date field

`print(address.save(force_update=True))`

Comment: `save()` doesn't return anything, so no you can't. But I don't understand your problem, can you maybe rephrase it, maybe English is not your native language but this sentence is hard to understand? An example would clarify it.

Comment: tnks, my problem is i need to check if a table has changed in an update to apply a change to a time field

Comment: the only way is to fetch a fresh instance from the database and compare it to the current one before you save it. SQL doesn't tell you if a change was made when you `UPDATE` a row.

Comment: Or, if you're interested in a specific field, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Comment: this was my fear, I thought that as django uses an abstract form it could return a rows_affected like the PDO to php

Comment: That would incur a cost, because it would have to fetch the "old" instance before updating it. How else could it tell what was changed?

Comment: would be a form of an address, where it would change a time field every time that form was changed

Comment: I already gave you 2 ways to determine if it was changed. Try it.

Comment: yes, very tnks.