# How to prevent changing slug value when updating the post if the title has not changed?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a purpose about learning django and rest framework. So I faced a problem when I worked on a tutorial project. The slug value changing every time when the article object updating. If the title value has not changed, I want the slug value not to change either. How can I handle this process?

For example:
When I update article but I haven't made any changes to the title field, the slug value also changes.

before update

```
"title" : "article 1",
"slug" : "article-1",
```

after update

```
"title" : "article 1",
"slug" : "article-1-1",
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # taslağa kaydetme işlemi
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=150, editable=False)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="media/post/%Y/%m/%d/", blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="modified_by")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.title.replace("ı", "i"))
        unique = slug
        number = 1
        while Post.objects.filter(slug=unique).exists():
            unique = '{}-{}'.format(slug, number)
            number += 1
        return unique

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        self.slug = self.get_slug()

        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["user", "title", "content", "created", "modified", "slug", "image", "modified_by"]
```

**views.py PostUpdateAPIView Class**

```
class PostUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
    permission_classes = [IsOwner]

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(modified_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: well, you _are_, unconditionally, calling `self.get_slug()` in `save()`...

Comment: I know that but I didn't know how to control it until just now. I have knowledge with help of Maciej M's answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save()` method is being called on object creation and update. Therefore, you should call `get_slug` method only when value of title hasn't changed.

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
            self.slug = self.get_slug()
        else:
            orig = Post.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if orig.title != self.title:
                self.slug = self.get_slug()
        self.modified = timezone.now()

        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Please be informed that this solution creates additional call to database.
Better, but a little more complex solution is to use `post_save` signal.
[When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Comment: It works for me, thank you for your help. I thought this solution but I didn't know how to prevent that additional call. Now I have knowledge about that topic. Also thank you for this link.
I applied your solution and working pretty well. It's about tutorial project that's why an additional call isn't a problem for now. However, if I work on a real project, I must pay attention to this matter, I will.