# Django How to cleaify if the value is changed in models save method

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this one:

```
class Exam(BaseModel):
    ...
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        (PASS, PASS),
        (FAILED, FAILED),
        (GREAT, GREAT),
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default=PASS)
    ...
```

Now I want orderride the save method and know if the state field is changed or not:

```
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        if self.__state != self.state:
            print('changed')
        super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

The `self.__state` seems wrong, how can I do that?

Comment: You want to know it the `state` field changed from what? You mean, if it is set to something other than the default value? Or do you mean if it is different than what is in the database? Please formulate a more precise question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When saving, how can you check if a field has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)

Comment: I got the answer from @ilyasbbu but I don't know I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname' – 
error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you want to override the **init** method of models.Model so that you keep a copy of the original value. This makes it so that you don't have to do another DB lookup (which is always a good thing).

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES = (
    ("PASS", "PASS"),
    ("FAILED", "FAILED"),
    ("GREAT", "GREAT"),)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default="PASS")

    __original_state = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_state = self.state

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.state != self.__original_state:
            print("changed")
            # state changed - do something here

        super().save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__original_state = self.state
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has been thoroughly solved and discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed) including the edge cases, limitations and benefits of each approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write this yourself. Use the Fieldtracker from the model_utils package to check if data has changed: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker