# Is there a robust way to automatically set update_fields when saving a model?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I've been having some issues with Django model saving and concurrency.

It seems unnecessary that every time you call `.save()` on a model it overwrites every field even if you're only intending to write one field. I can't think of a specific use case for why that would be the default behavior since it is safer for concurrency and more performant to only write the necessary fields.

I was thinking about expanding off of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed) to automatically determine which fields have been updated to specify `update_fields` (if they aren't already specified) accordingly in the save method.

**Question:** Assuming we can reliably determine which fields on a model have been updated (in memory since last database read), is there a reason we shouldn't automatically restrict the `update_fields` in the `.save()` method to those updated fields?

I understand determining the updated fields may have caveats such as deferred fields.

Comment: Where Django does this is more in the Forms API. Form objects check fields for changes, so one option to do what you want is to subclass `ModelForm` to pass along its fields to the underlying model's `save()` method. I can't speak for the design decision, though.

Comment: One question that follows thing might be. Now that this is the design, what should we do about concurrency issue.

Comment: The way I have done it is `new_data = form.changed_data` then `model.save(update_fields=new_data)`

Comment: @Ehsan88 This would not solve the concurrency issue but it would significantly improve it, especially for models with lots of fields. To actually solve the concurrency issue we would need to involve database locks which would reduce performance. This solution would be a compromise for non-critical models

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This may work in a simple scenario of updating directly from form data but I am considering a more general solution where the data may be changed through a series of nested operations or a cronjob etc. My question is not necessarily how one would implement this but whether it's a good idea in the first place.

Comment: 1) In Postgres an UPDATE is going to save everything anyway, as an update is basically a delete of the entire old tuple and an insert of the entire new tuple. 2) I am not following what you want as your question specifically refers to model.save() and updated_fields. Those may not  be available elsewhere. 3) Postgres use [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html) so concurrency is built in. In particular read [Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Postgres UPDATE does not save everything: _The columns that do not appear in the SET clause retain their original values._ from [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update/). The concurrency problem is a Django problem, not a Postgres problem. It arises when you get a model (database read) and then call `.save()` later where in between that time, the database row has been modified by another process. When calling `.save()`, by default it overwrites all columns to the values in memory.

Comment: 1) Yes but behind the scenes Postgres during an UPDATE essentially marks the entire existing row(tuple) as deleted and then creates an entire new row(tuple) with all the columns, changed or not. So if you think  `update_fields` is going to help with storage and or performance that is not the case.  2) As to concurrency that is going to depend on the transaction isolation as detailed at the link I posted earlier. This can be influenced from Django end by using operations shown here [Transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/transactions/)